# is using partition disk software same like we partitioning itself

Tags: partitioning, disk-utility

i want to make new partition on my disk and im thinking of using software to make new partition.

but i have some question on my mind:

1. is using partition disk software same like we partitioning itself?if not, what is the different?

   2.and there is a disadvantages if using partition disk software?

--
in case: i only have localdisk C, then i create new partition using 3rd party disk partitioning software. i move my data to the new partition, then i reinstall my localdisk C. is that alright and will my data save?

Hope, you understand me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I grew up in the days when such partition software started to be released, and people declared the software was not reliable enough to be trusted.  Since then, this type of software got better.  However, I would still back up data I cared about, just in case it does not go well.  One minor error can cause a large amount of data loss.

Comment: @mook765 thx, you answering my question, but i cant accept it as an answer, because you write it in comment

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking if 3rd party disk partitioning software is better or worse than using the existing operating system's partitioning software.

The short answer is that an operating system's built in partitioning software should be perfectly capable of partitioning a disk to use with the same operating system.

You would use 3rd party disk partitioning software if you wanted to create a partition that in not native to the installed OS - as in creating a Mac or Linux partition on a Windows machine.  You might use a 3rd party tool in order do some advanced partition management as well.

As for disadvantages, there arent many.  Aleays read the manual with the software and know its limitations and known bugs.  And ***ALWAYS*** create a backup before making any changes to your disk.

Comment: in case: i only have localdisk C, then i create new partition using 3rd party disk partitioning software. i move my data to the new partition, then i reinstall my localdisk C, is that alright and will my data save?

Comment: Yes. If you create a second partition, move the data to it and then change the contents of the first partition (by reinstalling the OS on that partition) then it will change the data on the first partition but not on the second. Still, always make a backup. Not just in case of accidentally clicking on the wrong disk when asked to format, but also for fire, theft, lack of coffee, ....

Answer (score 0):

I used third-party partition-managers a lot ( Aomei, Paragon, Easus) and never had any issue using them. This tools do the same thing like Windows built-in disk-manager, but they have a lot more features.

To have your private data on a separate partition is a good idea as it will make you able to reinstall Windows easily without loosing this data. Remind that you should still use backups on another drive, even if your data are stored in it's own partition. If the Windows-drive fails totally this data-partition would be gone as well, so backups on another drive are likely a must.